Add a button below the product images woocommerce
Welcome
Use the code
add_action ('woocommerce_product_options_advanced', 'ecommercehints_product_data_metabox');
function ecommercehints_product_data_metabox() {
   echo '<div class="options_group">';
   woocommerce_wp_text_input (array (
      'id'                => 'demo_url',
      'value'             => get_post_meta (get_the_ID(), 'demo_url', true),
      'label'             => 'Demo URL',
      'description'       => 'The button link'
  ));
   echo '</div>';
}

add_action ('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'ecommercehints_save_field_on_update', 10, 2);
function ecommercehints_save_field_on_update ($id, $post) {
      update_post_meta ($id, 'demo_url', $_POST['demo_url']);
}

function ecommercehints_content_after_add_to_cart_form() {
   global $product;
   $demo_url = $product->get_meta ('demo_url');
   echo '<a class="button" href="' . $demo_url . '" target="_blank">View Demo</a>';
};
add_action ('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'ecommercehints_content_after_add_to_cart_form', 10, 0);

but
It displays the button below the Add Product button
enter image description here
I want to change the location of the button and make it below the product image
enter image description here
What is the way to do that?
I tried to modify the code but I couldn't

Welcome
I tried the code
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'custom_field_button' );
function custom_field_button() {

    $wp = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wp_button', true );
    
    $acf = class_exists('acf') ? get_field('acf_button') : '';
    
    $field = $acf ? $acf : $wp;
    
    if ( $field && is_singular('product') ) {
        
    printf( '<a href="%s" class="button" target="_blank" rel="”nofollow” noopener">' . __( 'Custom Button' ) . '</a>',  $field ); 
    
    }

}

But it appears for a few seconds and then disappears

You should change your action_hook (woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form). You can use this Visual Hook Guide for convenience. Please note that if you are using a custom theme, it may override the defaults. You can try and use woocommerce_after_single_product_summary or woocommerce_before_single_product_summary but you may have to add additional css.
